# how to make real time gauge chart using anychart?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gauge, anychart

I use node.js and javascript for creating a program.

I want to create a real time gauge using anychart, but the anychart gauge chart doesn't change although the data is coming from socket.io.

I want to access the anychart gauge chart object and change the data that was received from the socket.

How can I solve this problem?

```
anychartObj = new RealTimeAnyChart(elementId);
chartArrayList.push(anychartObj);

function RealTimeAnyChart(elemntId){

        this.dataSet = anychart.data.set([15]);
        this.gauge = anychart.gauges.circular();
        this.gauge.data(this.dataSet);
        this.gauge.container(elementId);
        this.gauge.draw();
}

socket.on(' ',function(){
    chartArrayList.gauge = value ?? this part is problem..
}
```

Comment: after changing data you need to redraw the chart to reflect new value. 
Or you can also read this https://api.anychart.com/anychart.core.Chart#autoRedraw

Comment: There is perhaps an unintended (?) typo in your attached code. You list `elemntId`as a parameter in the `RealTimeAnyChart` function, but you refer to `elementId` later below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new dataSet and apply it to you circular gauge like this:

```
socket.on(' ',function(){
var newData = anychart.data.set([20]);
chartArrayList.gauge.data(newData);
}
```

If you have an access to the existing dataSet object you can apply new data right to the old dataSet and do not create a new one. You can achieve that like this:

```
dataSet.data([20]);
```